# Azure CLI to check VM status

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Azure CLI allows people to `start` & `stop` VMs.

However, is there any Azure CLI command that can show the VM status? I.e., whether it is started or being stopped? Thx.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the '-d' flag with list and status for all VMs

```
az vm list -d -o table
```

For single VM, you can use:

```
az vm list -d -o table --query "[?name=='vm-name']"
```

If you need more specific results then you can also try:

```
az vm list -d --query "[?powerState=='VM running']" -o table
```

Comment: That's indeed a better option than the accepted answer. Thanks & welcome to SU with my +25.

Comment: I just love that az vm list gives me 174 lines of output per VM, including all sorts of esoteric settings that the doc barely explains, but then if you give it --show-details it  only outputs a whole 7 extra lines!
And *that's* where they decided to hide the VM state, because who could possibly want to know **that**!!

Comment: Just an add on; If you are working with az cli and powershell it is help full to use convertfromjson and look at it that way instead of using table.

Comment: For single VM you can use `az vm show -d` instead. In both cases it's the `-d` (`--show-details`) that's important.

Comment: show will list a whole bunch of information, a lot more than just the powerstate

Answer (score 7):

You can get the vm status with this command:

```
az vm get-instance-view --name vmName --resource-group resourceGroupName --query instanceView.statuses[1] --output table
```

The output will like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also run query in Azure Resource Graph Explorer

```
Resources
| project name, location, 
   PowerState=tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.code), type
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
| order by name desc
```

Answer (score 1):

all these answers did not work for me
I had to use

```
az vm show -d --resource-group my-rsg-name --name my-vm-name --subscription my-subsciption-id --query "powerState"
```

this just shows: [image]